# redis ping is not responding in python. no response. nothing

Tags: database, caching, redis, ping

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port, password=redis_password)

r.set("msg:hello", "Hello Redis!!!")

msg = r.get("msg:hello")
print('msg is',msg)
```

above code does not do anything. no error. nothing. Similar logic is working in nodejs btw.

Comment: is the key at least stored in the redis server?